# Unitary transformation to a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, toeplitz-matrices

Suppose it is known that a matrix $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ has a factorization of the form $M=UT$, where $U,T \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $U$ is unitary and $M$ is Toeplitz.  Is it possible to explicitly compute such matrices $U$ and $T$, and if so how?  Thank you very much.